# @ operator at the beginning of the line in python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand what does this operator @, uses in python.
I saw something about matrix multipication , but this is sure not the case,I'll give an example:

```
 @property
 def num_reserved_ids(self):
    return 0
```

Or:

```
 @registry.register_problem()
 class LibrispeechNoisy(Librispeech):
```

Last one:

```
@registry.register_hparams
def transformer_librispeech_tpu_v1():
"""HParams for training ASR model on Librispeech on TPU v1."""
    hparams = transformer_librispeech_v1()
    update_hparams_for_tpu(hparams)
```

Registry is another file that is used in the program.register_hparams is a function inside.
Don't know what "property" is, but even registry that I know what it is, I can't understand the purpose of the operator :@, I'm a bit slow, sorry for that :/ ..

If anyone wants to look for some more code you can check tensor2tensor library:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/tree/master/tensor2tensor

Comment: It's called a _decorator_ but your examples are a bit diverse for me to think how to answer this.

Comment: `numpy` uses `@` as the matrix multiplication sign. standard Python uses it for [decorators](https://www.thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/).

Comment: I didn't duplicate on purpose,if that's what you're saying, I searched and nothing returned, but thanks for another source of information.

Comment: @albert1905 nobody suggested that you did, and please don't take duplicates as some indication you did something wrong. You found a different way of wording some problem, so it will act as a signpost to the correct explanation :) Now a different combination of words in a Google search are more likely to get someone to the answer they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called PythonDecorators

Here is the [Wiki For Python Decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)

> A Python decorator is a specific change to the Python syntax that allows us to more conveniently alter functions and methods (and possibly classes in a future version). This supports more readable applications of the DecoratorPattern but also other uses as well.

The best way to understand them is from [Corey Schafer's Video on Python Decorators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsAPt_9Bf3U)